# Configuring Workingset into Maven pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

Is there any way to configure a project POM to be added to a specific Eclipse Workingset when update the project configurations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible. The WorkingSet configuration it's not stored within the .project nor in the .classpath files.

This information is stored in:
workspace/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml